# VS Code rust-analyzer doesn't work with items created inside derive macro

Tags: rust, intellisense, rust-proc-macros, rust-analyzer

I'm starting to mess around with proc macros. I created a derive macro for my structs to auto implement the type state builder pattern. It's working pretty well, but none of the structs created by the macro are picked up by intellisense (auto complete doesn't work, inlay hints show `!`) even though the code compiles and works as expected. Is there a way to fix this?

Also, in case this is editor specific, I'm using VS Code.

Comment: This looks like it should probably be a feature request on the [`rust-analyzer` tracker](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust-analyzer/issues)